# Short story about alternate world seen through a crack in a wall

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

Here is a vague description of a story I'm trying to identify:

In the story, there is some sort of a support group for people who have glimpsed, through doors or cracks in walls, other worlds and/or other dimensions. At least one person tells a story about looking through a crack(?) and seeing a world with an unearthly sky and strange trees. I believe that the title of the story includes the phrase "Layers of An Onion" or "Skin of An Onion."

This is the best I can do.

Comment: Any idea when you read it? Was it new then? Was it in a magazine, an anthology?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like it could be "Onion" by Caitlín R. Kiernan. One [review](http://www.locusmag.com/Reviews/2011/10/gary-k-wolfe-reviews-caitlin-r-kiernan/) says

> The story begins with the seven-year-old Frank glimpsing an impossible world of crimson fields through a crack in his basement wall,

Here's a list of places it's been published: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?102047.